# Reagent doesn't rerender component with deref-ing inside of let

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have atom `foo`:

```
(defonce foo (r/atom "foo"))
```

I have parent component:

```
(defn parent-component []
  (js/setTimeout #(reset! foo "bar") 5000)
  (child-component {:foo foo}))
```

And I have child component:

```
(defn child-component [props]
  (let [derefed (deref (:foo props))]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:p derefed]
       [:p (deref (:foo props))]])))
```

Only second paragraph is updated after reseting `foo`.

Why is it working that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the re-frame documentation regarding Form-2 components: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function.

You need to repeat the outer function parameters again in the inner function:

```
(defn child-component [props]
  (fn [props]
    (let [derefed (deref (:foo props))]
      [:div
       [:p derefed]
       [:p (deref (:foo props))]])))
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use form-2 components for such cases when you're using re-frame and its subscriptions: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/issues/218